# Integer stored as incorrect value in when using mmap

Tags: c, binaryfiles, mmap

Im writing a program that will write an array of structs to a file using mmap. The problem is the third integer value (left) is not being stored properly. When looking at the file through `od`, the bytes in `left` seems to be shifted one byte to the left. For example...

```
|loc            |value  |left          |right          |extra bytes?
001 000 000 000 103 120 000 000 000 003 000 000 000 004 000 000 //expected
001 000 000 000 103 120 000 000 003 000 000 000 004 000 000 000 //result
```

```c
typedef struct{
    int32_t loc;
    char value[2];
    int32_t left;
    int32_t right;

}Node;

Node newNode(int i);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    int result;
    Node *map;  /* mmapped array of int's */

    int filesize = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) * sizeof(Node);
    int numvalues = filesize / sizeof(Node);

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("File failed to open");
        exit(1);
    }

    //I dont know why this makes it work but we need to move the file pointer around for some reason.
    result = lseek(fd, filesize-1, SEEK_SET);
    if (result == -1) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek()");
        exit(2);
    }

    // same with this
    result = write(fd, "", 1);

    /* Now the file is ready to be mmapped.
    */
    map = (Node *) mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(4);
    }


    for (i = 0; i <numvalues; ++i) {
        map[i] = newNode(i);         /* here is where I save the data */
    }

    munmap(map, filesize);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

Node newNode(int i) { /*This method is where the structs are made*/
    Node n;
    n.left = i * 2 + 1;
    n.right = i * 2 + 2;
    n.value[0] = (char)(rand() % ('A' - 'Z') )+ 'A';
    n.value[1] = (char)(rand() % ('A' - 'Z') )+ 'A';
    n.loc = i;

    printf("%d, %d, %c, %c, %d\n", n.left, n.right, n.value[0], n.value[1], n.loc);

    return n;
}
```

also, why are some of the integers saved as little endian and others big endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting two issues: endianess and struct padding.

### Endianess

It appears your system is little endian. That means the least significant byte is stored first. We can see this in the fact that `1` is stored as `01 00 00 00`. In a big endian system it would be `00 00 00 01`. That means your "expected" result is not correct. It should be as follows. Note the left and right bytes have been swapped.

```
|loc            |value  |left          |right          |
001 000 000 000 103 120 003 000 000 000 004 000 000 000
```

### Struct Padding

So why don't you get the above expected result? Because the compiler adds padding in the struct for word alignment. So there are two pad bytes after `value` field. Print out `sizeof(Node)` to see that. Hence everything is actually shifted right by two bytes. So the actual expected result is:

```
|loc            |value  |pad     |left           |right          |
001 000 000 000 103 120  000 000 003 000 000 000 004 000 000 000
```

Which is exactly the actual result you have shown.